# Excuse me, I want to know why this program crashes?

Tags: file, class, object, crash, fstream

I learn how to store object class in a file and how to get it back.
But I don't know why this program crashes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class person{
public:
    string wife , son , mother;
    int brothers_num , sisters_num;
};

int main()
{
    person Ahmed;
    Ahmed.wife = "Aya";
    Ahmed.son = "Badr";
    Ahmed.mother = "Fatma";
    Ahmed.brothers_num = 2;
    Ahmed.sisters_num = 2;
    fstream new_file;
    new_file.open("database.txt" , ios::out );
    if(new_file.fail()){
        cout<<"can't open the files\n";
    }
    new_file.write((char*)&Ahmed , sizeof(Ahmed));
    new_file.close();

    person Khaled;
    new_file.open("database.txt" , ios::in);
    new_file.read((char*)&Khaled , sizeof(Khaled));
    new_file.close();

    cout<<Khaled.wife;

    return 0;
}
```

I write any thing as the website wants that

Comment: Be aware that this is not a safe way to serialize binary objects. Your object will have different size in debug build and release build, and also in 32 bit and 64 bit, giving you at least 4 different binary formats.

Comment: Another thing to consider: you can store e.g. 2kB in a string. sizeof(person) gives you values between 80 and 128 bytes (see comment before) - but how will the 2kB string be stored in that number of bytes?

Comment: Would you mind giving a link to the website which teaches this?

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. But I don't understand most of your comment as I'm at the beginning of learning. Can you explain in more detail or you can give me a link that explains that in detail?

Comment: This is the link that tou want https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-class-objects-fromto-file-c/

Comment: Thanks for the article. I'd say that code is as wrong as yours. You didn't make any mistake. You just followed a tutorial which is crappy. Unfortunately nobody else commented. I'd be happy to have some other opinions on this, but IMHO this simply won't work.